# Access a variable from another script using GetComponent

Tags: variables, unity-game-engine, global, unityscript, unity-components

In unity (the game engine)
I have two scripts

```
CharacterSelect.js
CarCameraScript.js
```

I want to access the variable

```
selectedPlayer
```

FROM characterSelect.js IN CarCameraScript.js

That variable currently looks like this:

```
var selectedPlayer : int = 0;
```

From what i hear is it has something to do with getcomponent. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: if the variable is somehow accessible from the global scope, you should be able to access it in your other script, if it is included after the one, where the variable got declared.

Answer (score 2):

you must create an instance of characterSelect.js in CarCameraScript.js

write in CarCameraScript.js

```
var characterSelectInstance : characterSelect;

characterSelectInstance = GameObject.Find("Name_Of_GameObjct_Where_you_attached_characterSelect.js").GetComponent(characterSelect);
```

so you can use it in CarCameraScript.js

```
var xyz : int ;
xyz = characterSelectInstance.selectedPlayer;
```